# Does "pmset schedule wake" work when the lid is closed at the designated time?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, pmset

I am using Air, which is in the sleep mode almost all day. I want to have it run a shell script every morning, so I set my Air to wake up at 7:00 using "pmset" command and run the script at 7:01 using another command. However, this does not work when the lid is closed and is unconnected to power at 7:00, and the script is not run until I wake it up by myself.

Does "pmset schedule wake" work when the lid is closed and connected to power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is no, because the act of having the lid closed is designed to put the Air to sleep (this is done with magnets). The only exception is [closed clamshell mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834) where you need:

- power connected
- display connected
- external keyboard + mouse or trackpad (bluetooth or USB)

You can watch the power events with `pmset -g pslog` so if you were to set a wake and then have terminal.app or other command line to watch the log, you could look at things when you wake up the Mac via lid open or external display. [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032) would be the only way you might get some events run with the lid closed and not in clamshell mode.

Also, while I haven't tried doing what you're trying to, I have noticed that allowing 5 minutes for a scheduled wake event is usually a better way to go.

So you could try running the script a little later (e.g. 7:05), or perhaps setting the Air to wake at 6:56. However, as I stated above, the lid being closed means the magnet will trigger a sleep event.

Comment: I didn't know about closed clamshell mode and Power Nap. Thank you for your detailed explanation. I will also try to run the script a little later. You helped very much!