# Can I make my MacBook remain sleeping when normal wake events happen for as long as the lid is closed?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, closed-clamshell

I recently got a dock / hub for my MacBook. A single USB-C connection provides power and connects it to my external monitor, keyboard, and mouse.

When I'm actually using the computer, I always have the lid open. Whenever the lid is closed, I want it to sleep. But it doesn't. Even if I explicitly click `Apple -> Sleep`, it will wake if the mouse is jiggled slightly, so I find the monitors turning on when I'm not using the computer.

Is there a setting for "remain asleep until the lid is opened"?

Comment: I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.3. [The answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412849/my-macbook-pro-doesnt-sleep-when-lid-closed) says to click `Apple -> Sleep`, but that doesn't keep it asleep.

Comment: If the lid is closed, I want the main screen to be the 27" - which works fine. I can put it to sleep with the left lower corner and wake up with spacebar. Shutdown is shutdown though.

Comment: @SolarMike You seem to have a different use case in mind than I am asking about.

Comment: I wonder if some combination of `pmset` would be effective. The first triage step is to get a [power event log going so you can visually see](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282115/5472) the various power events and then tackle them sequentially if no one has a “one and done” solution.

Comment: @bmike that's neat, I didn't know about `pmset`. But I was imagining there was a toggle somewhere like "when the lid is closed A) sleep B) use external monitors". If MacOS doesn't make that easy, I'll probably just unplug the dock and plug in a plain charger.

Answer (score 1):

I unplug the cable and let it sleep in this case. At work, I have a Logitech MX Keys keyboard and mouse and will sometimes unplug that USB Radio Dongle to keep it asleep as I want it to run but not wake if someone jostles the mouse.

Waking up while in clamshell mode is baked into the firmware so I don’t think there’s an obvious way to disable it.

Something like the [Twelve South BookArc](https://www.twelvesouth.com/products/bookarc-macbook) (or perhaps a solid wood / black walnut wood stand) work very well for me to make the cable swap a snap.